# Send json response to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

Am using following code to get some response from client machine  and getting that response properly .But i have to send that response to Jquery.I dont know how it is possible?"

```
var getOsLists = function(context){
 var options = {
            host: '172.16.2.51',
            port: 9090,
            path: '/vm/osList',
            method: 'POST'
        };
 var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (data) {               
                    console.log(data);  

                                                   // return sendJson(data, 404);

            });
        });
        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
        req.end();
}
exports.getOsLists = getOsLists;
```

i want to get the above data in the below section

```
function getOsList() {
    $.getJSON('/getOpSystem', function (data) {
            alert(data.toString()); // it does nt print anything
        var html = '';
        data.forEach(function (n) {
            alert(n);
            html += '<option value="' + n.ID + '">' + n.ID + '</option>';
        });
        $('#os').html(html);
    });
}
```

and in node.js

```
case '/getOpSystem':
          objSchedule.getOsLists();
          break;
```

Comment: Try like this http://askhds.blogspot.in/2012/02/nodejs-rest-call-using-http-library.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework. It provides a `res.json()` method that lets you pass through a Javascript object. The framework will handle stringify-ing the object to JSON, which jQuery can read.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/getOpSystem', function(req, res) {
    var system = [];
    //make a request, put response in `system`
    res.json(system);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Alternatively, you can set the `dataType` option to "text" in a `$.ajax` request and parse on the browser side:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text'
}).done(function(data) {
    //do something
    var array = data.split(',');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no a valid JSON (you may check it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)). 
**{}** means an Object and you must separate objects either with **comma** or **semi-column**.
**semi-column** means to assign it to different variables; **coma** means that it is an array

So it should be something like

```
[{"ID": "VM-WIN7-64","OS": "Windows 7"},
 {"ID": "VM-WIN7-32","OS": "Windows 7"},
 {"ID": "V M-WIN7-32-1","OS": "Windows 7"},
 {"ID": "VM-WIN7-32-2","OS": "Windows 8"}
]
```

I made it as an array because you're using data.forEach

Answer (score 0):

Just send the response as JSON, in express.js is as simple as this:

```
res.json(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Ajax post call to send data to server. Check the code

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
   })
   .done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
```